# How to calculate div position relative to the total browser area?

Tags: javascript, windows, google-chrome, browser

How to calculate the div position relative to the total browser area?
Example:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEzxq.png

I'm referring to the position relative to the entire browser area.

The orange rectangle is at x249 and y346, how i could automatic get this position?

I mean, is possible to read it somewhere or do i need to read something and do a math calc?

Answer (score 0):

```
elem.getBoundingClientRect().x
elem.getBoundingClientRect().y
```

Where elem is the html object(div, span etc.)

Comment: The value returned is not relative to the browser full area, i think the `Y` returned is relative from the `bookmark toolbar` until the element, im trying to get the `Y` position from the top until the element, from top i mean the browser top border.

Answer (score 0):

```
var divletposition= document.getElementById("div_id").offsetLeft;
var divtopposition= document.getElementById("div_id").offsetTop;
```

You can test on the below link

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_prop_element_offsettop

Comment: When i try `document.getElementById("containerWrapper").offsetTop;` or `left`, both returns 0

Comment: You can check on below link
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_prop_element_offsettop